# Xmonad change keybinds based on keyboard layout

Tags: xmonad, haskell

Is there there a way to define different keybindings in Xmonad depending on the current keyboard layout? For example, if I switch between standard US and Dvorak keyboard layouts, is there a way to have, say, mod+o spawn different applications based on which layout I'm currently using?

It's easy enough to have a plain-text file somewhere that keeps track of the keyboard layout (e.g. have a script which writes the keyboard layout to a file whenever it's changed). Then to determine which keyboard layout is active, Xmonad would simply have to read this file. The issue is that I don't know how have Xmonad load different sets of keybinds depending on what this file says.

I have no experience with Haskell, so please forgive my ignorance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-vanessa-2.1.0.1/docs/XMonad-Util-Keyboard.html

```
parseKB :: IO KbLayout
```

The above gives you the layout it seems.

Then you just do a conditional with this, (please note this is untested - just a rough idea):

```
example :: X ()
example = do
  x <- liftIO $ parseKB
  case x of
   "us" -> windows W.focusDown
   "dvorak" -> windows W.focusUp
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not sure if it works or not, but I also came across the following which may solve my problem: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.15/docs/XMonad-Actions-KeyRemap.html